# How to define transfer variables when solving equations in 1stOpt?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, equation-solving, nonlinear-equation

I am trying to solve a non-linear integration equations in 1stOpt. The parameters to be solved are *x1, y1, Uratio*, and 5 transfer variables are used to build the equations: *Left, Right, C, pl, pr*.

============================

Problems

1 The code doesn't run at all
2 I don't know how to difine the transfer variables
3 I'm not sure the use of int() is correct

## Original code

```
Constant  alph=pi*15/180, L=0.116, Tice=18, addweight=0.212, T0=15, dL=-0.02, tilt=0.1, heightofweight=12.5, forcefromcable=0, muL=0.001, rhoS=920*0.95, rhoL=1000, Cps=2049.41, hm=334000+Cp_s*T_ice, KL=0.57, Pe=102770, g1=-addweight*9.8, g2=-0.38*9.8, heightofmasscenter=0.07, heightofcable=0.13, d = pi*L*sin(alph)/2, M = g1*(dL*cos(tilt)+heightofweight*sin(tilt))-g2*heightofmasscenter*sin(tilt)-forcefromcable*heightofcable*sin(tilt), G = g1+g2;

Parameter  x1[0,], y1[,0], Uratio;

//transfer variables
Left = x1^2+y1^2-2*x*(x1*sin(alph)-y1*cos(alph)+x^2);
Right = x1^2+y1^2-2*x*(x1*sin(alph)+y1*cos(alph)+x^2);
C = (int(x*Right^2,x=0:L)-int(x*Left^2,x=0:-L))/(int(Left^1.5,x=0:-L)-int(Right^1.5,x=0:L));
pl = 12*muL*rhoS^4*hm^3*Uratio^4*(int(x*Left^2,x=y:-L)+C*int(Left^1.5,x=y:-L))/(rhoL*T0^3*KL^3)+Pe;
pr = 12*muL*rhoS^4*hm^3*Uratio^4*(int(x*Right^2,x=y:L)+C*int(Right^1.5,x=y:L))/(rhoL*T0^3*KL^3)+Pe;

Function  int(pl*y,y=-L:0)+int(pr*y,y=0:L)+M/d=0;
          int(pl,y=-L:0)*sin(alph+tilt)+int(pr,y=0:L)*sin(alph-tilt)+G/d-2*L*Pe*sin(alph)*cos(tilt)=0;
          int(pl,y=-L:0)*cos(alph+tilt)-int(pr,y=0:L)*cos(alph-tilt)+2*L*Pe*sin(alph)*sin(tilt)=0;
```

Comment: Can you update your post with some more detail on what you mean when you say "the code doesn't run at all?" Surely there is some error message somewhere.
Also, usually a good idea to say which programming language you're using somewhere in your post or in the tags!